# Spanning set for the Vector space of a Diagonal $3x3$ Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, span

what is a spanning set for the vector space of a diagonal $3\times 3$ matrices?
How would I determine this?
Im familiar with diagonal matrices eg:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & b & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & c \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

but I amm unsure how I would represent this as a span.

Comment: Those three $n$'s that you have written in your depiction of a diagonal matrix… can they take on three independent values? That would be very relevant to your question.

Comment: @ChrisChevalier A note on MathJax: the way to get a matrix like $\pmatrix{n & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & n & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & n}$ is by typing up `$\pmatrix{n & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & n & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & n}$`.  Formatting your questions with [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) makes them more readable and more likely to be answered.  Just something to think about in the future. :)

Comment: While I agree that this edit makes for a more sensible question, it's not entirely clear to me that it is consistent with the OP's intent. Perhaps he really **did** mean diagonal matrices with equal entries down the diagonal, i.e. $\pmatrix{n & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & n & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & n}$.

Answer (score 2):

A $3\times 3$ diagonal matrix has always the following form

$$\begin{bmatrix}a & 0 & 0\\0 & b & 0\\0 & 0 & c\end{bmatrix}.$$
where $a,b,c$ are real numbers.
Now we can write it as the following sum:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a & 0 & 0\\0 & b & 0\\0 & 0 & c\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\0 & b & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & c\end{bmatrix},$$

which is just

$$\begin{bmatrix}a & 0 & 0\\0 & b & 0\\0 & 0 & c\end{bmatrix} = a\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} + b\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} + c\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$$

This means, every $3\times 3$ diagonal matrix can be represented using the three matrices

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.
$$